# How to get all characters of an arbitrary encoding?

Tags: python, python-3.x, unicode, character-encoding

If I want to know which letters are part of the ascii charset, I can simply ask python, which is nice:

```
>>> import string
>>> string.ascii_letters
'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ'
```

I searched for a while, but couldn't find a generic function that returns charsets of arbitrary encodings. Something like this:

```
>>> import string
>>> string.get_charset('latin1')  # doesn't exist =(
'abc ... äöü ...'
```

Or did I just miss it? A function that checks whether a string only contains characters of some encoding would work too, but I'd like the intuitiveness of just having all valid characters as a list.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As far as I'm aware, no such function exists in the standard library.

In lack of a better idea, here's an ugly hack that tries to encode every single character in the utf8 range with the specified encoding and removes those characters that couldn't be encoded:

```
def get_charset(encoding):
    all_chars = ''.join(chr(x) for x in range(0x110000))
    return all_chars.encode(encoding, errors='ignore').decode(encoding)
```

Output:

```
>>> get_charset('latin-1')
'\x00\x01\x02\x03\x04\x05\x06\x07\x08\t\n\x0b\x0c\r\x0e\x0f\x10\x11\x12\x13\x14\x15\x16\x17\x18\x19\x1a\x1b\x1c\x1d\x1e\x1f !"#$%&\'()*+,-./0123456789:;<=>?@ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ[\\]^_`abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz{|}~\x7f\x80\x81\x82\x83\x84\x85\x86\x87\x88\x89\x8a\x8b\x8c\x8d\x8e\x8f\x90\x91\x92\x93\x94\x95\x96\x97\x98\x99\x9a\x9b\x9c\x9d\x9e\x9f\xa0¡¢£¤¥¦§¨©ª«¬\xad®¯°±²³´µ¶·¸¹º»¼½¾¿ÀÁÂÃÄÅÆÇÈÉÊËÌÍÎÏÐÑÒÓÔÕÖ×ØÙÚÛÜÝÞßàáâãäåæçèéêëìíîïðñòóôõö÷øùúûüýþÿ'
```

Speed test:

```
In [2]: %timeit get_charset('latin1')
306 ms ± 8.34 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
```

Comment: Note: this solution could miss some possibilities. Unicode code points are not characters. You may need to look also combining codes. The good: One of the first mission of unicode: be capable of doing to convert from and back without loosing information. So most important codec (pre 1990) should be ok For some Asian encoding developed around Unicode origin, you may miss some characters.